# Could a slider be considered duplicate content when used on all pages of my site?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have content in my HTML slider and I am showing it on all web pages. Do crawlers consider this content duplicate?

Comment: The catch all question about duplicate content should address your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Crawlers are pretty smart now a days. It shouldn't be an issue assuming that your pages have content on them other then your sliders.